# VS17 Installation: Bootstrapper has stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently created a windows server on Windows Server 2008 operating system. Once I had done that I tried to install Visual Studio 2017, I have tried all versions including community professional and enterprise. All of them show the same error as soon as I run the setup for each one as the image I have posted below.

[screenshot can be viewed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGAk.png)

Problem details:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe
  Application Version:  15.0.293.51136
  Application Timestamp:    588935a6
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7c78c
  Exception Code:   e0434f4d
  Exception Offset: 000000000000a49d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.1296.17
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Is VS2017 even supported on Windows Server 2008? It's an OS that's almost a decade old now...

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows Vista in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 is [not supported by VS2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)

Comment: How far back would I have to go to get a working version for 2008? Would VS 2015 work?

Comment: If you have WindowsServer2008 R3 SP1 [it would work with VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs)